# Present UIViewController using full page curl?

Tags: iphone, curl, uiviewcontroller, transition

Is their a way to use a full page curl to present a UIViewController?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean using the `UIViewController presentModalViewController:animated:` method. There's not a vanilla way to use a full page curl with this method.

However, you can still use the `UIView transitionFromView:toView:duration:options:completion:` class method (or pre-iOS 4 equivalent methods) to get the desired effect. I'll leave the modal view's dismissal and memory management up to you, but your presentation can be handled similarly to this:

```
OtherViewController * otherVc = [[OtherViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

[UIView transitionFromView:self.view 
                    toView:otherVc.view 
                  duration:TRANSITION_TIME 
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp 
                completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                    // Do something... or not...
                }];
```

Comment: It works except it doesn't register that the other view was presented even after i add the view controller in the completion

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't register"? Is there a specific callback you're looking for? Outside of a UINavigationController/UITabBarController you need to explicitly call `willAppear:`/`didAppear:`/`willDisappear:`/`didDisappear:` methods. You can call the expected methods in the completion block.

Answer (score 0):

`UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl`is what's available. Anything more or different you'll have to implement it yourself using [CoreAnimation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html) or worse [OpenGL ES](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/05/opengl-es-from-ground-up-table-of.html)